# change text on linkbutton on masterpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Im looking to change the text on a linkbutton on a masterpage when a user clicks a button on a content page and the resulting action meets certain criteria.
Is this do-able? I cant seem to access the masterpage controls via intellisense, which I suppose makes sense, but is there a way around it?

thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property in the code behind of your master page like this:

```
public LinkButton LButton
{
    get { return lButton; }
    set { lButton = value; }
}
```

At the top of your .aspx page, add this directive with a virtual path to your master page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master.master" %>
```

Rebuild the solution and in the code behind of your .aspx, you are able to do this:

```
Master.LButton.Text = "foo bar";
```

EDIT: If you want the text to persist over other pages:
When the certain criteria is met, you could instead set a session variable:

```
Session.Add("Link Button Text", "foobar");
```

In the Page_Load of the MasterPage:

```
if(Session["Link Button Text"] != null)
{
   lButton.Text = Session["Link Button Text"].ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: On my master page, I have '<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn" Text="foo" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>'. The code behind for the master page has the property 'public string LButton { set { lbtn.Text = value; } }'. On my aspx page, I have a directive with a virtual path to my master page and, in the Page_Load, I have 'Master.LButton = "bar";'. That changes the LinkButton's text to "bar".

Comment: This was done really quickly, and I want to add that this isn't the way I would do it in the end. I would have a property for the LinkButton that had a getter and setter, and that would work real well. I just did it in a rush.

Comment: @DarkWinter not a problem. Just elaborated hardcore in the answer just in case.

Comment: When the certain criteria is met, you could instead set a session variable: 'Session.Add("Link Button Text", "foobar");' and in the Page_Load of the MasterPage, 'if(Session["Link Button Text"] != null) { lButton.Text = Session["Link Button Text"].ToString(); }'

Comment: @DarkWinter, I saw your other comment. I was just trying different ways, and was deciding on which I liked the most. Sorry for taking so long.

Comment: Hi again, using set { lButton = value; } works great for setting the text value for a button, can I do something similar to make a masterpage button enabled / disabled?  cheers

Answer (score 3):

You have to find the control in the master page using the `FindControl` method, like...

```
(ControlType)Master.FindControl("controlID")


((LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkButtonID")).Text = "New Text";
```

Comment: You can also cast the Master as you MasterPage class name and then access the control through it... ((SiteMaster)Master).linkButton1.Text = "New Text";

Comment: just tried, not getting the controls in intellisense, get as far as ((SiteMaster)Master).

Comment: As in my comment, casting the MasterPage only opens up public properties on that MasterPage.

Comment: its just as above, ((SiteMaster)Master).linkButton1.Text = "New Text";   but after the first "." I aint getting any controls listed

Answer (score 0):

Use the Master keyword. So Master.control will access a control on the master page.

Comment: I think you mean the MasterType directive?  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To provide another alternative to the solutions given, you could also consider giving the master an interface:

```
public interface IMaster
{
   string LinkButtonText { get; set; }
}
```

Apply this interface to the code-behind of the master.  Then do in the page:

```
((IMaster)Page.Master).LinkButtonText = "XYZ";
```

Also, if you have a custom base page class, you can shadow the Master property and return this interface instead, so you can directly reference it.

HTH.